# jpa merge unmanaged entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I would like to make an unmanaged entity managed in another Persistence Context. I read that this can be made with merge:

```
em.merge(user);
```

But if I do this it is not added to the context:

```
boolean isManaged = em.contains(user);
```

is always false.

Even if I make the following:

```
User dbuser = em.find(User.class, user.getId());
em.merge(user);
boolean isManaged = em.contains(user);
```

The dbuser and user are exactly the same.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using JPA, MySql DB, JBoss EAP 6.1

Comment: Did you begin and commit a transaction? Further, do: `dbuser = em.merge(user);`

Comment: Can I start a transaction with JPA (without Spring etc. or native Hibernate)? I just use @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)

Comment: One could get the transaction object with `em.getTransaction()` for calling `.begin()`, `.commit()`, `.rollback()`. However, that might not be necessary or even impossible (when using a JTA EntityManager) in your configuration.

Comment: user = em.merge(user); did the trick. thanks. (even without find(). as expected)

Comment: You're welcome. Just noticed, that I accidentally mixed up `user` and `dbuser`...

Answer (score 0):

Call `entityManager.flush()`to commit your merge action into the database.

Ususally the commit is delayed. For example if your method has an `@TransactionAttribute` annotation. The transaction will be commited after the method has finished. But if you call `em.contains(user)` without a commit you just get the old state.